# Javascript - matching first value from array search with value from other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, search

So let's say we have two arrays

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 5,];
```

I want to return just the first matching value without doing two for loops. So not by taking first value from `arr1` look for it in `arr2` then second value ect.

I this case I would need to return `4`.

Working in React/Redux enviroment without jQuery possible.

Comment: Any special reason why you don't want loops?

Comment: Probably his teacher said not to do it.

Comment: I working with quite a large number of data so the for loops take long time to execute. Last one I did took around 20 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 5,];

arr1.find((x) => arr2.indexOf(x) >=0);
```

That'll grab the first match

Comment: Shouldn't it return `indexOf(x) > -1`?

Comment: @pete `0 >= 0` is the same as `0 > -1`

Comment: Didn't see the `=` :). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find()` with `includes()` method.

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 5,];

var r = arr1.find(e => arr2.includes(e));
console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ecmascript5 solution (with `Array.some()` function):

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 5,],
    result;
 
arr2.some(function(n){ return arr1.indexOf(n) !== -1 && (result = n) })

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the power of [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
const
    arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 4, 5],
    result = arr2.find((s => a => s.has(a))(new Set(arr1)));

console.log(result);
```